# Oracle SQL - Order data stored in a database

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting

I was wondering if anyone knows if there is a way to sort the data that already resides in a database. That is, I want to sort what is there but NOT retrieve it in in query.

I am asking because I have a list of things in this database, that I would like to add to in future and would like to order it once I've added them.

So what I mean is, I would like to not have to download all the data; sort it; then put it back onto the database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow? You want to know how to sort the data? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp

Comment: Rows in a relational database are **not** "sorted". Sort them when you retrieve them. The ***only*** (really: the **only**) way to sort a result is to use an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Data in a table is not sorted; you order it when you query it. What you're asking doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Of course data can be stored sorted, using index organized table, when it's beneficial. You still need to use the ORDER BY clause in a query to ensure the order because reading of an index can be FAST FULL or when you run parallel query so the blocks are not read and processed in order but Oracle doesn't need to sort the data.

In Oracle 12c there is also attribute clustering which is very beneficial for hybrid columnar compression and zone maps but the order is not guaranteed like when an index is used.

Comment: @Husqvik *Of course data can be stored sorted, using index organized table* that's also not true. In IOT, rows are logically sorted in primary key order, and not physically.

Comment: @Husqvik - "the order is not guaranteed like when an index is used" - the order is not guaranteed when an index is used either (even with an IOT). If there is no `order by` clause, you might get lucky depending on how Oracle accesses it, but it'll surprise you one day. As you sort of pointed out earlier in your comment.

Comment: @Husqvik: You are right that index-organized tables store data pre-sorted, so as to get the data out sorted quickly when specifying the corresponding ORDER BY clause. This has its limits though, and a simple WHERE clause can slow down access significantly, so most often you are better off with a normal table and appropriate indexes. So while your statement is true, I wouldn't recommend to switch to IOTs generally.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  You might ask another question that describes something that you actually want to accomplish, rather than asking for functionality that is not natively part of relational databases.  Tables represent *unordered* sets.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one column in your table then this is fine and you can simply sort the data in that table.

But if there are more than one columns in your table then it would be dependent on the other columns as well(ie, you need to specify which column you are looking to sort.) <strike>Also if there is a primary key attached to the table then its not possible as primary key would be in ascending order by default. In that case you can only have it while selecting the data from the table.</strike>

*(My suggestion is to sort the data while selecting your records from the table as that would be easy and will have less risk)*

**EDIT:**

To make my point straight and clear, the best way to achieve what you are trying to simply use **ORDER BY ASC** or **ORDER BY DESC** while you are selecting the data from your table.

If you are creating a new table then you can create **index organized table** to ensure that the data is stored ordered by index.

Comment: "*if there is a primary key attached to the table then its not possible as it would be in ascending order by default*" this is wrong. Rows are not sorted and the existence of a primary key will not change that (especially not in Oracle)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:- It was for the primary key ie, primary key is by default in ascending order. Isnt it?

Comment: No, it isn't. And even if the primary key _index_ was in "ascending order", it doesn't mean the table is stored like that as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:- Agreed. I never intended to say that the table will be stored like that. What I meant was if the primary key is attached then it would be tedious to modify the table by sorting it. Instead my suggestion was to use sorting while selecting. Am I misleading?

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi: The records in a table are not sorted. You cannot sort them. You can only specify a sort order when retrieving the data with ORDER BY. As long as you don't specify an ORDER BY clause, there is no guarantee to get records sorted. So yes, your answer is misleading, as there is no choice.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if anyone knows if there is a way to sort the data that already resides in a database.

Normal relational tables, called as **heap-organized tables**, store rows in any order i.e. **unsorted**. You **sort** the rows if required only when you **fetch** them, not when you **store** them. And the only way to guarantee the sorting while retrieving the rows is to use an `ORDER BY` clause.