# Can't insert values order by column

Tags: java, mysql, sql

This is my first question on the website so please be forgiving :)

I have a project in sql and I try to order one of my tables in a way i seen here -

You would have to use a second table

create a new table games2 with the same structure as your games table, making sure the ID is auto-incrementing

```
CREATE TABLE `games2` LIKE `games`; copy the data, sorted, into games2

INSERT INTO `games2` (`Name`, `SomeDescription`) SELECT `Name`, `SomeDescription` FROM `games` ORDER BY `Name` drop or move the old table

-- DROP TABLE `games`;
-- or
RENAME TABLE `games` TO `games1`; rename new table to old name

RENAME TABLE `games2` TO `games`;
```

Unfortunately it does able to do all the lines, but it doesn't sort the code . it's only create new table games1 identically to the old

Here is my code if it's help :)

```
try {
    stt1.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS topten2" +
            "(username varchar(50) not NULL UNIQUE," +
            "country varchar(50) not NULL," +
            "score int)");
    stt1.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO topten2 (username, country, score) SELECT * FROM topten ORDER BY score");
    stt1.executeUpdate("RENAME TABLE topten TO topten1");
    stt1.executeUpdate("RENAME TABLE topten2 TO topten");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: Why is this tagged with sql-server? It looks like mysql.

Comment: For the question at hand...regardless of the DBMS there is one and only one way to get data ordered. That is to use an ORDER BY on your select statement. By definition a table is an unordered set.

Comment: This is certainly not SQL Server, as Sean said. SQL Server doesn't use backticks(`\` `) for quotes on objects, and `RENAME TABLE` is not valid T-SQL.

Comment: I'm uncertain where your example came from, but it seems to serve some special purpose and to make a lot of assumptions.  If one wants to select rows from a table in some particular order, then one normally asserts the order *in a query*.  One does not create a new table.  Tables are best viewed as not being inherently ordered.

Comment: @SeanLange you right my friend, sorry

Comment: @JohnBollinger https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079750/how-to-sort-values-in-columns-and-update-table

Comment: Isn’t the whole point of this exercise that you should have an auto increment ID column so that the new table will have ID values in the same sort order as the column you sorted on during insert.

Comment: That question seems to be asking something quite different from yours (as I interpret it), about how to reassign auto-generated primary keys so that their order matches some sort order on other columns.  So exactly as I said, it serves a special purpose and makes some assumptions (such as that the original table has an autogenerated PK).  And querying the resulting table *still* requires using an `ORDER BY` clause to guarantee a desired order.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that the table `games` is using InnoDB storage engine, and has a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE KEY` defined. (But we're just guessing.) InnoDB tables are always stored "in order" by the cluster key (the PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE KEY on a set of non-NULL columns). IMPORTANT NOTE: this physical ordering of rows in an InnoDB table is an artifact of the implementation; InnoDB always uses a cluster key. Other storage engines in MySQL do not have this quirk. A table is an *unordered* set of rows. To return rows in a specified order, we use an `ORDER BT` clause.

---

Using the `CREATE TABLE LIKE` statement (as shown in the question) will create a replica of the original table *including* the key definitions. It doesn't matter what order the rows are inserted, they will be physically stored in order by the cluster key... again because it's using InnoDB storage engined.

The physical order that the rows are stored in doesn't really matter. In terms of relational theory, a relation is an unordered set of tuples. Implemented in a relational database, a table is an unordered set of rows.

---

To add an auto_increment column, that will need to be defined as an integer type column, with the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute. (Note that we can add a column to a table using the `ALTER TABLE` statement.)

It looks like the requirement is to implement an surrogate key to serve as the `PRIMARY KEY` (cluster key) for the table. Creating a copy of the table is one way to achieve this, there are other approaches.

---

How about we do this. Get the definition of the existing table:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `mytable` ;
```

Then we take the DDL and modify that to change the name of the table, and include a new integer AUTO_INCREMENT column as the PRIMARY KEY, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable2
( id       BIGINT      NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'PK'
, username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE COMMENT 'UX'
, country  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
, score    INT 
);
```

Then we can "copy" the rows from the old table, providing a NULL value for the id column so that a value will be automatically assigned.

```
INSERT INTO mytable2 (id, username, country, score) 
SELECT NULL, s.username, s.country, s.score
  FROM mytable s
 ORDER BY s.score
;
```

And then the renames:

```
RENAME TABLE mytable TO mytable1
;
RENAME TABLE mytable2 TO mytable
;
```

Answer (score 1):

I infer that your expectation was that after the procedure you present, `SELECT` queries on the table involved would by default return rows in the same order they were inserted.  This is not a safe assumption, any assertions of [the answer on which you modeled your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079750/how-to-sort-values-in-columns-and-update-table) notwithstanding.  It is possible that it would happen, but by no means certain, and there's certainly no reason to expect any such inherent ordering to persist after any further insertions or deletions.

The most that code achieves is to reassign autogenerated primary key values for existing rows to be ordered consistently with the order of the sort key used.  That is of little use, at best.  If your database contains foreign key relationships on the modified table, however, then either the procedure will fail altogether or it will screw up those relationships.

SQL has no sense of *table* order.  Instead, it provides *result* ordering via the `ORDER BY` clause of `SELECT` queries.  If you care about the order of your query results then you specify whatever order you like as part of the query, with no need to modify the underlying table(s).  For example,

```
SELECT Name, SomeDescription
FROM games
ORDER BY Name;
```

Although implementations will typically exhibit idiosyncratic result ordering characteristics in the absence of an `ORDER BY` clause, you should not make any assumptions about result order when you omit `ORDER BY`.

Comment: absolutely. a table is an *unordered* set of rows. any observed ordering is an artifact of the implementation. we use `ORDER BY` clause to return rows in a specified sequence. +10

Answer (score 0):

Relational databases usually do not store records in any particular order.  The database engine does what it wants.  What you want to do is generally not possible, or only contrived for specific use cases.

For SQL Server:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/81dc5d09-a6b0-4be3-9dc6-e5fde0171365/can-i-sort-an-sql-table?forum=transactsql

For Oracle:
[Oracle SQL - Order data stored in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32268585/oracle-sql-order-data-stored-in-a-database)

For MySQL:
[Best way to change order of rows in MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351627/best-way-to-change-order-of-rows-in-mysql-table)